# How to generate different APK

Tags: android

I want use the same project to create two different apk(for example A.apk and B.apk).So I changed the "package" in manifest and the "applicationId" in build.gradle. The problem is the android phone also warning me to unstalled A.apk when I installed B.apk. Why? A.apk and B.apk has different package.
A.apk's main package name is "com.meimei.a",and B.apk's main package name is "com.quanquan.b".  I still can n't install A.apk and B.apk in the same phone.

Comment: you need to rename the actual java package as well as package in the manifest

Comment: You have to change the package name. Because Android always check the package name instead of application name.

Comment: modify the package structure in the application, then only you can generate different apk's

Comment: What do you mean teh package structure in the application? I also changed  the main package name from com.zfeng.a to com.test.b.  But the also have the same package com.meimei. Should I change the com.meimei package to another name?

Comment: @Andy.Zhao: What is your main package name? You need to rename the main package, Which is mention in mainifest.

Comment: A.apk's main package name is com.meimei.a and B.apk's main package name is com.caicai.b.

Comment: In Android studio, your gradle application ID would be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is the current project's provider has the same authorities with the old current. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using productFlavors in build.gradle and changing the application's applicationId for each flavor.

```
productFlavors {
    appStaging {
        applicationId "com.android.appname.staging"
    }
    appProduction {
        applicationId "com.android.appname"
    }
}
```

Building to a specific flavor using the above should result in separate apks that can be installed side-by-side.

In addition, you can even change the source you want in these apks by doing something like the following:

```
sourceSets {
    appStaging {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/appstaging/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/ui', 'src/appstaging', 'etc']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    }
    appProduction {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/app/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/ui', 'src/app', 'etc']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is the current project's provider has the same authorities with the old current.  Thank you all the same.